# why the output shown like that ? java

Tags: java, output, increment

i'm little confused why the out put gave me the value of **m** = 1111???
here is the code :

```
class X
{
    int m = 1111;

    {
        m = m++;

        System.out.println(m);
    }
}

class Y extends X
{
    {
        System.out.println(methodOfY());
    }

    int methodOfY()
    {
        return m-- + --m;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Y y = new Y();
    }
}
```

could you please explain why the output be like that ?

Comment: Note: `m = m++` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because of the execution order: first `X`'s variable is initialized (`m = 1111`), then `X`' initializer block is executede (`m = m++; System.out.println(1111);`, `m = m++;` does not change `m`'s value), then `Y`' initializer block is executed (`System.out.println(m-- + --m);`, which will be `2200`).

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: @Turing85 shouldn't the last number be `2220`?

Comment: Because the unnamed instance initializer block in the class is run when you create an instance of the class. As always, the base class gets constructed first, then the derived class. So `m` is initialized to 1111, then `m` is assigned the value of the post increment from the `m++`, but first assignment happens, then increment. So this is a no-op. `m` is then printed, and you get the 1111. After that the `methodOfY` is called, changes `m`  and prints it. This could be less confusing with constructors instead of unnamed initializers because people are more used to constructors.

Comment: @Turamarth yes, it should be. Typo on my side. I cannot modify the comment any longer.

Comment: i expect that the value of m will incremented by 1 , look at this example 

: 
  int x=10;
  int y =x++;
 int y =x++;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);

note that x value will be 11)
same that in m=m++ ,, it should be incremented by 1 in print statement

Comment: @AbdulRahman No, `x++` has `x`'s old value. If `x = 10`, then `x++`'s value is 10, thus you increment `x` to `11` and then immediately overwrite it with the old value (`10`).

Comment: aha,, thats okey :D 
Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution order is defined from super- to subclass and within the classes, first the static initialization of variables are executed, before initializer-blocks are executed. This gives the following order:

```
class X {
    int m = 1111; // 1st point visited

    // This is X's initializer block:
    {
        m = m++; // 2nd point visited: m's value is not changed, read below
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    // This is Y's initializer block:
    {
        System.out.println(methodOfY()); // 3rd and 5th point visited: 
                                         // 2220 is printed after
                                         // methodOfY() has been evaluated
    }

    int methodOfY() {
        return m-- + --m; // 4th point visited: m-- = 1111 (m = 1110),
                          // --m = 1109 (m = 1109), therefore 2220 is 
                          // returned
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Y y = new Y();
    }
}
```

Now to the pre- and postincrement operator. You can implement them "by hand"<sup>1</sup> to understand their behaviour:

```
public class PrePostIncrement {
    int value;

    public PrePostIncrement(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int preIncrement() {
        this.value = this.value + 1;
        return (this.value);
    }

    public int postIncrement() {
        int result = this.value;
        this.value = this.value + 1;
        return (result);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        PrePostIncrement test = new PrePostIncrement(1111);
        int newValue = test.postIncrement();
        System.out.println(newValue);
    }
}
```

As you see, the value returned by `postIncrement()` is `1111`. This will be the new value assigned to `m` in `X`'s initializer block. Thus, `m` will have the value of `1112` just for a very brief.

Since I do not expect you to simply believe me, I wrote some code showing exactly this behaviour:

```
public class Main {
    public static volatile int x = 0;
    public static volatile boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Thread observer = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                int x = Main.x;
                System.out.println("Observer observed: " + x);
                if (0 != x) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Main.running = false;
        });
        observer.start();

        while (running) {
            Main.x = Main.x++;
        }
        System.out.println(Main.x);
    }
}
```

As you see, `observer`'s only purpose is to print `x`'s value, until it sees `x`'s value as `1`. The main thread keeps executing `x = x++;` until `observer` has seen one change in `x`'s value. Afterwards, the final value of `x` will be printed. Please note that this program must be run on a true multicore-system, otherwise it may run in an endless loop.

On my system, I usually get one to six iterations of `observer` until the change is seen. The final value of `x`, however, will always be ´0´<sup>2</sup>.

P.S.: Welcome to the world of Java Concurrency. If one would write an application with multiple threads, that need concurrent access to `x`, one would most probably define `x` as [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and use the methods [`int incrementAndGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) (instead of `++x`) and [`int getAndIncrement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement--) (instead of `++x`). Those methods guarantee that the intermediate values of `x` are not seen by other threads.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Please never do such a thing. `++i` and `i++` are language constructs and highly optimizable by the compiler. This is only to demonstrate their behaviour.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>It is possible that even on a multicore-system this program runs in an endless-loop, but the programm will terminate [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely). Reasoning is that the probability of `observer` seeing `x`'s value as `0` is < 1 and something < 1 to the power of n for n towards infinity is 0.</sub>

Comment: Thank you @Turing85